# Discord bot returning odd error message and not playing sound

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, discord, discord.js

I am attempting to create a function of my discord bot that will join your voice channel then play something from youtube as specified in the command

i.e. `$play <youtube link>`

The problem is that my bot joins the voice channel but doesn't play any sound and outputs an error to the console that I dont know how to fix

### My Code:

```js
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'initiates music methods of the bot',
    execute(msg, args){
        var servers = {};

        function play(connection, msg){
            var server = servers[msg.guild.id];

            server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));
            server.queue.shift();

            server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
                if(server.queue[0]){
                    play(connection, msg);
                }else{
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            });


        }
        if(!args[1]){
            return msg.channel.send("you need to provide a link");
        } 
        if(!msg.member.voiceChannel){
            return msg.channel.send("You must be in a voice channel to use this feature");
        }
        if(!servers[msg.guild.id]) servers[msg.guild.id] = {
            queue: []
        }
        var server = servers[msg.guild.id];
        server.queue.push(args[1]);
        if(!msg.guild.voiceConnection) msg.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection){
            play(connection, msg);
        })
    }
}
```

### The Error:

```
2020-02-26T16:31:59.458215+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
2020-02-26T16:31:59.458223+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at validateString (internal/validators.js:117:11)
2020-02-26T16:31:59.458224+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at normalizeSpawnArguments (child_process.js:406:3)
2020-02-26T16:31:59.458224+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.spawn (child_process.js:542:16)
2020-02-26T16:31:59.458225+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at new FfmpegProcess (/app/node_modules/prism-media/src/transcoders/ffmpeg/FfmpegProcess.js:14:33)
2020-02-26T16:31:59.458225+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at FfmpegTranscoder.transcode (/app/node_modules/prism-media/src/transcoders/ffmpeg/Ffmpeg.js:34:18)
2020-02-26T16:31:59.458226+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MediaTranscoder.transcode (/app/node_modules/prism-media/src/transcoders/MediaTranscoder.js:27:31)
2020-02-26T16:31:59.458226+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Prism.transcode (/app/node_modules/prism-media/src/Prism.js:13:28)
2020-02-26T16:31:59.458227+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at AudioPlayer.playUnknownStream (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/player/AudioPlayer.js:97:35)
2020-02-26T16:31:59.458231+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at VoiceConnection.playStream (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/VoiceConnection.js:478:24)
2020-02-26T16:31:59.458232+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at play (/app/commands/play.js:11:44)
```

for reference these are the links I tested it with [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6LL5iA6y9o) & [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-oU2xlViRQ)

I'm not sure how to make queue[0] a string, which is what I assume the problem is.

I was thinking of using a toString() i.e. `server.queue[0].toString()` but I think that will just return the memory address.

If anyone can help me know what the issue is or how to fix it, that would be great.

Comment: Can you console.log the `server.queue` to make sure it is infact an array with valid video links?

Comment: well, when I remove the quotation marks from the ```queue[" "]``` part, and then log server.queue after pushing args[1], it shows my link and returns the error ```The "file" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object``` . I think I understand the issue now but I am not too familiar with nod.js syntax and I am not sure how to make the link a string.